# How to loop entire Selenium script X times

Tags: python, loops, selenium, salesforce

I have a Selenium script that logs into Salesforce, creates a contact with standard data and saves.

I would like to ask the running user how many contacts to create using raw input from the console and then loop the script x times until they have been created.

Would it be best to add this into the code below? Or enter a loop in the console when running this python file in Terminal?

Thanks!

NOTE: I have used a random int between 0-5000 to create a unique (near enough) last name and email so that duplicates are unlikely.

NOTE 2: I will only create max of 10 contacts before deleting and repeating the experiment.

Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
import time
from random import randint

class SalesforceLogin(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://test.salesforce.com")

    def test_salesforce_login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("xxxx")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("xxxx")
        driver.find_element_by_id("Login").click()
        time.sleep(1)

        # Generate random number and assign to lastRnadom
        lastRandom = randint(2,5000)
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Contacts").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("new").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("name_firstcon2").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("name_firstcon2").send_keys("Test")
        driver.find_element_by_id("name_lastcon2").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("name_lastcon2").send_keys(lastRandom)
        driver.find_element_by_id("con4").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con4").send_keys("xxxx")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con15").clear()

        # Form an email address from strings and ints
        email = ("test" + "@" + str(lastRandom) + ".com")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con15").send_keys(email)
        driver.find_element_by_id("con10").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con10").send_keys("012345678")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con12").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con12").send_keys("0123456789")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con5").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con5").send_keys("Mr")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con19street").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con19street").send_keys("Made Up Mailing Street")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con19city").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con19city").send_keys("Mailing City")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con19state").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con19state").send_keys("Mailing State")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con19zip").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con19zip").send_keys("Mailing Zip")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con19country").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con19country").send_keys("Mailing Country")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con18street").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con18street").send_keys("Other Street")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con18city").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con18city").send_keys("Other City")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con18state").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con18state").send_keys("Other State")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con18zip").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con18zip").send_keys("Other Zip")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con18country").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con18country").send_keys("Other Country")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con11").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con11").send_keys("Fax")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con13").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con13").send_keys("Home Phone")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con14").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con14").send_keys("Other Phone")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con16").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con16").send_keys("Assistant")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con17").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con17").send_keys("Asst. Phone")
        driver.find_element_by_id("con20").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con20").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("con20").send_keys("Description")
        driver.find_element_by_name("save").click()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: If you want to repeat this for x-number of times - why not surround the creation code with a loop? Or do you want to execute the entire class, so `setUp()` and `tearDown()` repeatedly as well, instead?

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried adding a loop into the top of the code but it just stops when it gets to the bottom of the script. Am I missing something?

Comment: Personally, I'd have just used a `for counter in range(0, 10)` loop. Declared on your line before your comment: "# Generate random number and assign to lastRnadom". As such it should execute your random number generator and account creation that number of times.

Answer (score -1):

Loop it our use concurrency. Sadly i cant suggest you any code as im doing my scripts in java.

Also your code is missing explicit waits so theres a chance it might fail during process.